# Is cpanel/WHM needed to run a webserver for a newbie?

Tags: linux, apache, security, webserver, cpanel

I am mostly focussed on web development and my main operating system is windows.
As a result of that I don't really have a clue about unix systems or webservers.

Now I wanted to get a VPS Server to host some of my websites but I'm not sure what to chose.

Reading some articles about web security, I don't know if I'll be capable of securing the webserver that it won't end up getting hacked or something else.

After research I found the following 2 options suitable for me:

*1 a Digital Ocean Cloud VPS - You basically get a VPS along with shell access and you're all on your own. There are some great tutorials and I'm sure I could get up a VPS running my website following tutorials but is that good? How big are chances of getting hacked if I don't know exactly what I do?

*2 A Small Orange Cloud VPS - I get free WHM/Cpanel and I think they also manage all their systems so security won't really be an issue and managing the server should be easy.

Also I'm wondering if WHM/Cpanel will take a lot of resources so the server would be slower than one running without it, is that possible or doesn't Cpanel/WHM affect the system speed?

I couldn't decide for days, are you having any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpanel is just a backend management utility. If you're just starting out, I'd say it's a requirement. I suggest grabbing some cheap linux based webhost. You can usually find them for $5/mo or so. Also, you can install VirtualBox, download a copy of Debian 32bit and setup your own server to practice on. GL.